# Spring creates two beans from one class using annotations

Tags: java, spring

I have can create from two beans from one java class using xml configuration using following code:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="some.package"/>

    <bean id="dependentBean" class="some.package.DependentBean">
        <property name="firstBean" ref="firstBean"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="firstBean" class="some.package.Handler">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="service"></constructor-arg>
        <property name="defaultUrl" value="url/first"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="secondBean" class="some.package.Handler">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="service"></constructor-arg>
        <property name="defaultUrl" value="url/second"></property>
    </bean>
```

My goal is move firstBean and secondBean to java based configuration like this:

```
package some.package;

@Configuration
public class Configuration {

    @Bean(name="firstBean")
    public Handler firstHandler(Service service){
        Handler handler= new Handler(service);
        handler.setDefaultTargetUrl("url/first");
        return handler;
    }


    @Bean(name="secondBean")
    public Handler secondHandler(Service service){
        Handler handler = new Handler(service);
        handler.setDefaultTargetUrl("url/second");
        return handler;
    }
}
```

But when context begins loading spring throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'firstBean' is defined
```

Nevertheless it works in this case:

```
package some.package;

    @Component
    public class Filter{

        private Handler handler;

        @Autowired
        public Filter(@Qualifier("secondBean") Handler handler) {
             this.handler = handler;
        }

    }
```

Handler implementation:

```
public class Handler {

    private Service service;

    @Autowired
    public Handler(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your full context? With whichever bean depends on `firstBean`.

Comment: Where exactly does that exception get thrown ? Is that caused by some autowiring with the bean name as qualifier ? If so, can you provide a little more of your context config and / or the relevant injection annotations ?

Comment: It caused when dependentBean try to load firstBean. I already updated context.

Comment: You're still missing the part where you're trying to inject the "firstBean". Without that, this is more like a spring quiz for possible scenarios rather than a question.

Comment: Are you sure there is not just a typo in your bean name or dependency definition? That would be the most probable cause from where I am standing :).

Comment: @PavelHoral: the error message complains about the right bean name, so, unless he edited that just to make the quiz more interesting... :)

Comment: @CostiCiudatu you know how the questions are written. Usually you don't copy and paste the actual code, but rather write it from scratch to be more simpler and understandable. I've lost too many hours hunting down non-existing bugs because of silly typos. Double checking never hurts.

Answer (score 1):

`@Autowired` is always by type. But you have two Handlers in your configuration. So when you try to autowire the handler class, you have to specify the qualifier. By this spring can resolve which instance to inject. Else, spring throws the error showing `NoSuchBeanDefinitionFoundError`. Expected one found two.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This can not be correct. The error clearly states that it tries to lookup bean by name. OP is using `@Qualifier`.

Comment: Thanks to all for answer. Actually my problem was in web.xml. I have two different context and exactly it does not enabled :)

Answer (score -1):

From the [Spring Docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-beanname), section 5.9.3:

> If you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do not primarily use @Autowired, even if is technically capable of referring to a bean name through @Qualifier values. Instead, use the JSR-250 @Resource annotation, which is semantically defined to identify a specific target component by its unique name, with the declared type being irrelevant for the matching process.

There's an example of this in section 5.9.5, but for your code, your **Filter** class should look like:

```
package some.package;

@Component
public class Filter {

    private Handler handler;

    @Resource(name="secondBean")
    public Filter(Handler handler) {
         this.handler = handler;
    }

}
```

Comment: Even thou this has a nice documentation quotation, it can not solve the issue. The error clearly states that it tries to lookup bean by name. OP is using `@Qualifier`.

Comment: -1 This might have be a useful answer for a question regarding best practices or something alike; for this particular question, your statement is useless. Besides, that statement is most likely quoted out of context.